# datediff error on SQL query but not using datediff at all

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm getting this error:

> Msg 535, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
> The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.

I am using SQL Server 2008. I am not using a `datediff` function but I get an overflow error above. The query below works on one of my DB with the same structure, but it doesn't work on this database on a different server. Do I have to change some DB settings to get this query to work?

```
SELECT [EventStamp]
      ,[AlarmState]
      ,[TagName]
      ,[Description]
      ,[Area]
      ,[Type]
      ,[Value]
      ,[CheckValue]
      ,[Priority]
      ,[Category]
      ,[Provider]
      ,[Operator]
      ,[DomainName]
      ,[UserFullName]
      ,[AlarmDuration]
      ,[User1]
      ,[User2]
      ,[User3]
      ,[EventStampUTC]
      ,[MilliSec]
      ,[OperatorNode]
  FROM [A2ALMDB].[dbo].[v_AlarmEventHistory2]
  WHERE [EventStamp] >= '2022-08-25' AND [EventStamp] <= '2022-08-26' 
  ORDER BY [EventStamp] ASC
```

Comment: The "table" [v_AlarmEventHistory2] is actually probably a view with calculated fields and something in one of those calculated fields is using Datediff.   Here's the clue: your DBA named the object with a v_ prefix, that should prompt you to think this is a calculated object (view).

Comment: At a guess, the DBA probably used `DATEDIFF` to truncate the `MilliSec` value, and used an epoch which is too far in the past, causing an overflow.

Answer (score 0):

the view you are using **[A2ALMDB].[dbo].[v_AlarmEventHistory2]** contains the DATEDIFF function and its overflowing either due to the reason there is NULL in the date or its extracting a date part which is overflowing its natural value limit.